# Почему QtCreator изменяет '.' при обращении к элементу класса на ->?

Tags: c++, ооп, qtcreator

Почему QtCreator изменяет '.' при обращении к элементу класса на ->? Хотя сама переменная не является ссылкой. В Qt нет точки?

Comment: Может, она является указателем? :)

Comment: Возможно... но я не ставил * после типа данных

Comment: @SergG разберитесь хорошо в ссылках и указателях. Это крайне необходимо чтобы хоть что-то дальше делать. Кажется, что у вас есть какое-то недопонимание в этом. -> используется, чтобы вызвать метод через *указатель* на объект

Comment: Вы бы с кодом спрашивали... а то прямо как-то неудобно получается :)